# 2 different substitutions to solve a first order homogeneous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I was in diferential equations class, I found a book which said you can use two types of sutitutions:
$y=ux$ or $x=uy$ to solve a First order homogeneous dif eq, sadly I've forgot the author's name, I checked some books and everyone uses $y=ux$ directly.

I remember there was a good reason to use $x=uy$ instead of $y=ux$ for some equations, do someone know about this?

Comment: You'll have to provide more information that that; What particular problem are you trying to solve? What books did you check? etc.

Comment: Well, not trying to solve a particular problem, I'm trying to find this algorithm to solve the first order homogeneous diferential equation (in general), in which, sometimes it seemed easier to use $x=uy$ instead of $y=ux$  (which is a suggested substitution for the general solution process).

Comment: http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~lee/calculus/DE.pdf this paper for example, uses $y=ux$.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.
Given a first order diferential equation in the form
$P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$, and $P$ and $Q$ are homogeneous functions of the same degree, you can use $y=ux$ or $x=uy$ as sustitutions to solve it, the solution will be given in the form:
$$\int \frac{dx}{x}= \int \frac{-Q(1,u)du}{uQ(1,u)+P(1,u)}+C$$
or

$$\int \frac{dy}{y}= \int \frac{-P(u,1)du}{uP(u,1)+Q(u,1)}+C$$
In the end it is enough to give $u$ back to original value, and you are done.

I'm guessing the choice of $x=uy$ or $y=ux$ should be based on the dificulty of the intergrals.